# Google Chrome to use SOCKS proxy when performing DNS queries: "proxy-bypass-list" vs. "host-resolver-rules"

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, dns, socks-proxy, socks5

I want to prevent DNS leaks over a SOCKS v5 proxy on Google Chrome, much like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60821841/chrome-option-proxy-bypass-list-loopback-is-not-working) StackOverflow question

So apart from the command-line flag to proxy traffic through the SOCKS v5, `--proxy-server`, I need an additional one to avoid local DNS flags not being proxied too.

The instructions in [chromium developers](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/socks-proxy/) site suggest adding `--host-resolver-rules` flag. However, in modern tutorials (and in the previous question) they use a different flag (`--proxy-bypass-list="<-localhost/loopback->`) for this same purpose.

The two commands would be:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" `
-ArgumentList '--proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1337" --proxy-bypass-list="<-loopback->"'

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" `
-ArgumentList '--proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1337" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * ~NOTFOUND , EXCLUDE 127.0.0.1"'
```

What are the differences between the two flags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brave browser shows error message in flags page when using `--host-resolver-rules="MAP * ~NOTFOUND , EXCLUDE 127.0.0.1"`.

Hence the correct flag is `--proxy-bypass-list="<-loopback>"`.